# What does envconfig.Process() do

Tags: go, environment-variables

I'm looking through some source code using [the envconfig library](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig) and am having trouble understanding what the below code does. I know it loads the environment variables but would like to understand what each specific line does. I was hoping somebody might be able to explain it to me. In particular what the line `envconfig.Process("", &Env)` does

```
 package config  
    import (
        "html/template"
        "log"
        "os"
    
        "github.com/joho/godotenv"
        "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
    )
    
    type envVars struct {
        Dbhost     string `required:"true" envconfig:"DB_HOST"`
        Dbport     string `required:"true" envconfig:"DB_PORT"`
        Dbuser     string `required:"true" envconfig:"DB_USER"`
        Dbpassword string `required:"true" envconfig:"DB_PASS"`
        Dbname     string `required:"true" envconfig:"DB_NAME"`
        JwtKey     string `required:"true" envconfig:"JWT_KEY"`
        HashKey    string `required:"true" envconfig:"HASH_KEY"`
    }
    
    //Env holds application config variables
    var Env envVars
    
    // Tpl template
    var Tpl *template.Template
    
    func init() {
    
        wd, err := os.Getwd() //get path of working directory(current directory) - directory of this project
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err, "::Unable to get paths")
        }
    
        Tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob(wd + "/internal/views/*.html")) //could use path.join in case it's used on linux instead of windows.
    
        
        //load .env file
        err = godotenv.Load(wd + "/./.env") //loads environment variable file so that env variables can be accessed in code eg. by using os.GetEnv("DB_DIALECT"), won't work otherwise.
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error loading .env file, falling back to cli passed env")
        }
    
        err = envconfig.Process("", &Env)
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Error loading environment variables", err)
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Documentation is pretty easy to come by: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig#Process - it reads the environment and populates the fields of the struct per the `envconfig` tags on the fields.

Comment: @Adrian thanks, but I can't seem to find what happens when it's an empty string as is this case. Does it read environment variables from cli?

Comment: It reads environment variables from the environment. A process cannot tell how an environment variable was set. If the env var is an empty string, the value you get will be an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[envconfig.Process()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig#Process) populates a given struct with values pulled from environment variables. Which environment variables are used can be specified with the `envconfig` struct tag.

For example:

```
Dbhost     string `required:"true" envconfig:"DB_HOST"`
```

The above will populate the `Dbhost` field with the value of the `DB_HOST` environment variable. If the `required` tag is set to true, `Process` will return an error if no matching environment variable exists.

You can use the `default` tag if you want to define defaults for the case where a matching environment variable does not exist:

```
Dbhost     string `default:"host1" envconfig:"DB_HOST"`
```

The first parameter to `Process` is a prefix in order to only match environment variables with a certain prefix.

For example:

```
envconfig.Process("DB", &env)
```

The above will only consider environment variables with a `DB_` prefix, e.g. `DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT`, `DB_USER`, etc. In your particular case, this would leave the fields `JwtKey` and `HashKey` unpopulated as the corresponding environment variables don't have a `DB_` prefix.

I would suggest reviewing the [README documentation on Github](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig) which provides some more detailed explanation and examples.